# Second time partialview not loading to div via from .ajax() in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have issue loading partialview to div second time. I have checked previous posts in SO but non of them really helped me. So I am posting my issue here.

index.cshtml

```
 <div id="DivEmailContainer" style="display:block" class="row">            
  </div>
```

_EditEmail.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 ">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success width100per" />
            </div>


script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
             $("#frmEmail").validate({
                 rules: {
                        ...
         submitHandler: function (form) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'PostEditEmail',
                        type: 'Post',
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert("In success");
                            $('#DivEmailContainer').html(result);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        },
                        complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                 }
            });
```

controller

```
public PartialViewResult PostEditEmail(string actiontype, FormCollection col)
        {
            var communicationLocation = string.Empty;
            ....
             return PartialView("_EditEmail", memberemail);
          }
```

First time partialview loading into `DivEmailContainer` to error. If submit again partialview  loading full post back. not even it is calling `submitHandler`.

Only thing I observed is 1st time submit `<form post` was `/ContactInformation/GetEditEmail`but when I submit second time `<form post` was `/ContactInformation/PostEditEmail`.

What could be wrong?

### update

second time Forloop scriptblock loading. May be it is issue with Forloop?

`@using (Html.BeginScriptContext())
{
    Html.AddScriptBlock(`

### update

issue with forloop htmlhelper, not with ajax. secondtime script is not loading. @Russ Cam can help on this.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a better description for people to be able to help. Please provide 1. The view from which the partial is called, 2. How the partial is called, 3. What the intention is i.e. what are you trying to achieve. Just a brief look at what you have, the JavaScript doesn't look like a good fit to be included in a partial using the helpers; the same script with the same content is being executed several times. If you could provide more detail as requested, I may be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

from my experience putting script in a partial leads to very inconsistent results.  expecially with the script being inserted into the middle of the page.  I would highly recommend that you pull your script from the partial and put it on the main page.  Since the partial is loaded after the page load you will need to tie the script to the partial one of 2 ways.
1. tie the events to the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.targetClass', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

for example to put an id on your input and change it to a button

```
<input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success width100per" />
```

your click event would then be

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function(){
   //your ajax call here
});
```

being tied to the document this click event would fire even though the input is inserted into the document after load

2. put the script in a function that is called after the partial is loaded
   change your

   $(function () {

to

```
function partialScript(){
```

and call this function after the partial is loaded

```
$('#DivEmailContainer').html(result);
partialScript();
```

Comment: my problem is the whole script block is not loading after 1st load

Comment: changed my answer.  from what I can see from your code, in the middle of the script running you are replacing the script.  Pulling your script out of the partial should fix your issues.

Comment: I am just confused with 2 option that you mentioned. I have couple partial view loaded in index.cshtml. like display/Edit for email and phone (display/edit). each partialview has script block. how manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load partial view like this

```
$("#DivEmailContainer").load('@Url.Action('ActionName', 'ControllerName')', function () {
                    //Perform some operation if you want after load.
});
```